# Editing an ASP.NET table control using the Design View in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I have spent a while searching google for an answer to the following question, with no luck.

Does anyone know if there is any way (at *all*) to use the Design view to edit the contents of an ASP.NET table control (an `<asp:Table runat="server">...`)?

From all that I can tell, devs are stuck coding their `<asp:TableRow>`s and `<asp:TableCell>`s by hand! This is ludicrous, given that you can use the design view as a WYSIWYG editor for standard HTML tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In design view go to the properties of your table and select rows and click the button.  You can add rows there. Likewise the row properties has a cells property that lets you add cells one at a time.

Still pretty bad but it would cut down on the hand typing.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Rows property you can play with in the design view.

As you add rows to the Rows collection, you have access to the Cell property as well through the dialog presented to you.